# C# Run method in a time interval

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, timer

I have this method that gets data from an api and saves it to a JSON file.

How can I get the JSON file to be updated every hour on the hour.

```
 public void saveUsers()
    {
        string  uri = "https://****dd.harvestapp.com/people";

        using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
            webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "application/json";
            webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(usernamePassword));

            string response = webClient.DownloadString(uri);

            File.WriteAllText(jsonPath, response);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the type of your host ? Winforms ? Console? Website ?

Comment: You can try [FluentScheduler](https://github.com/fluentscheduler/FluentScheduler)

Answer (score 3):

Use timer, add `object source, ElapsedEventArgs e` parameters in your `saveUsers()` method and make it `static`

```
private static System.Timers.Timer timer;

public static void Main()
{
    timer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);

    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(saveUsers);

    timer.Interval = 3600000;
    timer.Enabled = true;

}

 public static void saveUsers(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        string  uri = "https://****dd.harvestapp.com/people";
        using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
            webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "application/json";
            webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(usernamePassword));

            string response = webClient.DownloadString(uri);


            File.WriteAllText(jsonPath, response);

        }

    }
```

**Update**

Suppose you have a `MVC` controller name `Home` then you can start the timer from the `index` method

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private static System.Timers.Timer timer;
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            timer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(saveUsers);
            timer.Interval = 3600000;
            timer.Enabled = true;

            return View();
        }
    }
```

And keep one thing in mind because you want to run the timer in an hour interval so may garbage collector stop the timer before method call, you need to keep alive the timer, you can keep timer alive this way after starting the timer

```
GC.KeepAlive(timer);
```

Comment: i need it to be a mvc application

Comment: so you want it to start the timer from your Controller ?

Comment: @RobelHaile see my latest update, I have show how can you start the timer from `MVC` controller

Answer (score 1):

Make it a console application and use Windows Task Scheduler to call it with any frequency you want.

Comment: i need it to be a mvc application

Comment: Why? If you need MVC for other stuff you can have both the MVC app and the console app. From your code it doesn't look that it needs (nor should) be on an MVC app.