# C# loop for x milliseconds

Tags: c#, visual-studio, loops, time

I am creating a bot which shall excecute mouseclicks as long as the timer goes but not longer than this. Like leftmouseclick than for 387ms it should do/spam rightmouseclick and wait 10ms between each click of rightmouseclick

Now I am searching for a way to do/spam the rightmouseclick in a loop for some milliseconds (not in an interval!).

Like:

```
for(387ms)
{
   doSomething(); // doSomething() is rightmouseclick in my case
   wait(10ms);
}
```

Where doSomething() gets excecuted as much as possible inside the 387ms timeframe and the wait(10ms) shouldn't affect the time remaining like I think it would be when using `Thread.Sleep(10)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Run method in a time interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37090005/c-sharp-run-method-in-a-time-interval)

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov You can't duplicate a question for another that was closed as 'too broad' with no answer; not to mention the answers suggested are timers which isn't an answer to the question at all.

Comment: What you ask is not easy to accomplish. First, you would need to determine the time left until the 387ms time frame is over. Then, you would need to know in advance how much time the next call of doSomething() would take exactly. Which is nigh impossible (unless you would switch to some realtime OS and implement doSomething() in some other programming language where a constant execution time for doSomething() could be guaranteed...)

Comment: Thus, let me ask you what exactly you want to achieve with this approach? What is your root problem you try to solve? Because what you are asking here sounds very much like a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me...

Comment: It is okey if doSomething() gets executed and run to the end even if it exceed the time limit but it shouldnt start another doSomething()

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII - it is perfectly fine to close one "too broad" question as duplicate of another "too broad" question... If you feel need to discuss whether it is ok - welcome to meta.
 Also in this particular case it is not good duplicate and question is not too broad (maybe unclear what OP actually don't know how to do).

Comment: @elgonzo I try to make a bot which shall excecute mouseclicks as long as the timer goes but not longer than this. Like leftmouseclick than for 300ms it should do/spam rightmouseclick and wait 10ms between each click

Comment: @elgonzo I think they are doing game loop of some sort like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647974/how-to-implement-a-fixed-step-loop

Comment: Hmm, i would choose a different approach. Use some timer that you set up to fire every _n_ milliseconds (which is the frequency of the mouse clicks you want to achieve). In the timer event, execute doSomething and count the timer invocations. After so and so many timer invocations stop the timer. (if doSomething should be called every 10ms over a period of 300ms, the number of timer invocations should be max. 300/10 = 30. To stay within the allotted time period, perhaps rather choose (300/10)-1 = 29...

Comment: (Note that if you want to invoke doSomething() every 10ms without overlap, its execution time needs to be comfortably less than 10ms...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess while is more appropiate for this and you can call below function to get what you want.

```
    public void TimerLoop(int ms)
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now; 
        while(DateTime.Now < now.AddMilliseconds(ms))
        {   
        //do your stuff here
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Here are two methods, `TimeLoop` and `TimeLoopAsync` that will loop an action for a specific amount of time at a specific delay.  Take what you need from it but it will accomplish what you're looking for.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int TotalTimeMS = 200;
            const int DelayMS = 10;
            TimeLoop(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"First {DateTime.Now.Ticks}");
            }, TotalTimeMS, DelayMS);

            await TimeLoopAsync(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Second {DateTime.Now.Ticks}");
            }, TotalTimeMS, DelayMS);

            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static void TimeLoop(Action action, int totalTime, int delay)
        {
            var futureTime = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(totalTime);
            while (futureTime > DateTime.Now)
            {
                action.Invoke();
                Thread.Sleep(delay);                
            }
        }

        public static async Task TimeLoopAsync(Action action, int totalTime, int delay)
        {
            var futureTime = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(totalTime);
            while (futureTime > DateTime.Now)
            {
                action.Invoke();
                await Task.Delay(delay);
            }
        }
    }
}
//OUTPUTS
//First 636813466330097482
//First 636813466330207562
//First 636813466330317509
//First 636813466330427504
//First 636813466330537519
//First 636813466330647498
//First 636813466330757504
//First 636813466330867485
//First 636813466330977501
//First 636813466331087479
//First 636813466331197483
//First 636813466331307522
//First 636813466331417580
//First 636813466331527516
//First 636813466331637533
//First 636813466331747513
//Second 636813466331867481
//Second 636813466332197479
//Second 636813466332317508
//Second 636813466332427498
//Second 636813466332647472
//Second 636813466332757495
//Second 636813466332977526
//Second 636813466333087469
//Second 636813466333197468
//Second 636813466333417483
//Second 636813466333527481
//Second 636813466333757457
//Done
```